# Math for video stabilization per axis translation with Accelerometer not gyro

Tags: gyroscope, accelerometer

Moth stabilization math is around gyro based sensors (pitch, roll and yaw) however they cant correct per axis movement. But in many phones digital stabilization methods uses accelorometer to do that. Does anyone know the math behind using accelorometer to stabilize end video?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask generically for an exposition on a subject are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.